# как обновить pull request на github?

Tags: github, update, pull-request

Старый еще не принят, новый не возможно добавить. 
Compare across forks, сделать не выходит. Возможно вышли какие то обновления..

Comment: «не возможно добавить» — как именно невозможно? Вы из той же ветки хотите ПР или из новой?

Comment: один и тот же форк, но разные пул. старый пул не замержен по этому новый не могу запулить